# Best way of accessing data on different pages

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm looking for a way to load data into properties/variables etc and have this information accessible to all the pages of my app.
I want the information to be loaded via a background thread to keep UI thread free. Some of the pages will have various properties of their controls binding to these global properties.

Here is what I tried.

- Created a static class. All pages could access the data but can't bind.
- Changed the static class to a Singleton and used DependencyProperty's. All pages could access data and binding worked fine but cross-threading issues when accessing via background threads.

I have read in various places on this subject but haven't really come up with the best method yet for my situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably have each page bind to different [ViewModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) objects, and let your ViewModels worry about accessing/updating the data in your "static" class.

If that's not an option, remember that `DependencyObject` is not the only way to go if you want to bind a page to an object. I personally prefer using [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). This way you can have the UI update data on the UI thread and still be able read data on a different thread. Of course you're going to need to write your code in such a way that it is [thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/261683/138757), but at least you won't get an exception when accessing properties that your UI is bound to.

Also note that singletons [have their downsides](https://stackoverflow.com/q/137975/138757). If I were you, I'd probably use [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/130794/138757) as an alternative if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can't update the UI directly with a background thread in Xaml-based applications.  All UI updates need to be done via the Dispatcher on the UI thread.

To ensure that you are using the Dispatcher thread in a WP7 application (which is really just Silverlight) you would do something like:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => this.Detail = _staticObject.Detail);
```